# Distribution Dirac-delta example

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am learning about distributions and I'm looking for an example for which the following holds:

Let $F_f(\phi):=\int_{\mathbb R^2} \phi(x)f(x)dx$ where $\phi \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb R^2)$ and $f$ is locally-integrable.

Find $f$ for which $-F_f(\nabla^2\phi)=\delta(\phi)$ holds, where $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta distribution

Would appreciate any help

Comment: $$f(x,y) = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$